# REQUEST_URI PHP

Tags: php

Прошу помощи, что я не так делаю?
Логотип на странице не отображается.

```
<?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == 'site-1.ru') { ?>
<a title="На Главную" href="/"><img alt="На Главную" src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/images/logo.png" /></a>
<?php } elseif ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == 'site-2.ru') { ?>
<a title="На Главную" href="/"><img alt="На Главную" src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/images/logotype.png" /></a>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Спасибо, решил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] возвращает не site-1.ru (для главной страницы), а слэш (/)

Answer (score 0):

А должен?
Сделайте следующее

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SERVER);
echo "</pre>";
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == 'site-1.ru') {
 ...
}
?>
```

И посмотрите что у вас находится в REQUEST_URI. Вероятно не то, что вы ожидаете.

Comment: Возвращает "/"
Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно написать условие так, чтобы при обращении по адресу site-1.ru показывался один логотип, а при обращении к другому site-2.ru, другой логотип? В этом деле я дилетант.

Comment: Видимо ещё не проснулся, все спасибо, решил проблему самостоятельно.